# QML : Binding loop detected (MWE)

Tags: qt, qml

Есть два `Rectangle`: `rectParent` и `rectChild`:

- `rectParent` имеет длину и ширину на 10 пикселей больше, чем у `rectChild`, причем у `rectChild` стороны заданы жестко
- `rectChild` находится по центру `rectParent`

Логично, что `rectParent` для вычисления своих размеров обращается к `rectChild`, который, в свою очередь, обращается к `rectParent` для вычисления анкеров.
Но `rectParent.height` вычисляется исключительно из `rectChild.height`, которые заданы жестко. И потом из `rectParent.height` (и координат, на которые дочерний объект не влияет) вычисляется `rectChild.verticalCenter`.

Вопрос: откуда взялся цикл (хотя отображается всё корректно) и как всё же сделать по фен-шую?

QML MWE:

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("mve")

    Rectangle {
        id: rectParent
        color: "#bbb"
        width: childrenRect.width + 10
        height: childrenRect.height + 10

        Rectangle {
            id: rectChild
            width: 200
            height: 50
            color: "#ddd"
            anchors {
                horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Warnings:

```
qrc:/qt/qml/CenterTheDiv/Main.qml:11:9: QML Rectangle: Binding loop detected for property "height"
qrc:/qt/qml/CenterTheDiv/Main.qml:11:9: QML Rectangle: Binding loop detected for property "height"
qrc:/qt/qml/CenterTheDiv/Main.qml:10:9: QML Rectangle: Binding loop detected for property "width"
```

Comment: Нигде не вижу childrenRect